# Adding vector fields

Tags: calculus, soft-question, vector-fields, visualization

Consider two vector fields:

$$ \vec F_1=(\sin(x),\sin(y)) $$

$$ \vec F_2=(\sin(1-x),\sin(y)), $$

where $x,y \in(0,\pi).$

Does adding the two superimposed vector fields produce a net vertical flow, $\vec F_3$?

$$ \vec F_1+\vec F_2=\vec F_3 $$

What does $\vec F_4=\vec F_1 \times \vec F_2$ look like?

Can I see a picture of all four vector fields?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) can answer all of your questions, I think.

#### Picture of $\vec F_1$

[`vector plot (sin(x),sin(y)) for x from 0 to pi and y from 0 to pi`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vector%20plot%20(sin(x),sin(y))%20for%20x%20from%200%20to%20pi%20and%20y%20from%200%20to%20pi)

[image: F1 plot]

#### Picture of $\vec F_2$

[`vector plot (sin(1-x),sin(y)) for x from 0 to pi and y from 0 to pi`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vector%20plot%20(sin(1-x),sin(y))%20for%20x%20from%200%20to%20pi%20and%20y%20from%200%20to%20pi)

[image: F2 plot]

(Are you sure you didn't want $\sin(\pi-x)$ instead of $\sin(1-x)$?)

#### Picture of $\vec F_3=\vec F_1+\vec F_2$

[`vectorplot (sin(x),sin(y))+(sin(1-x),sin(y)) for x from 0 to pi and y from 0 to pi`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vectorplot%20(sin(x),sin(y))%2B(sin(1-x),sin(y))%20for%20x%20from%200%20to%20pi%20and%20y%20from%200%20to%20pi)

[image: F3 plot]

#### Picture of $\vec F_4=\vec F_1\times\vec F_2$

For this we have to be careful. The main definition of cross product does not apply to 2D vectors like these. However, if we treat $\vec F_1$ and $\vec F_2$ as 3D vectors with third component $0$, then we can take their cross product as normal, and it's somewhat common to do so. We'd get $\left(0,0,\sin(x)\sin(y)-\sin(1-x)\sin(y)\right)$. Since all of the values of the cross product are multiples of $(0,0,1)$, we may as well just take the number in the third component, which is occasionally called the "scalar cross product" of 2D vectors. This is Wolfram|Alpha's default interpretation, as in their [vector algebra examples](https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/mathematics/linear-algebra/vectors/).

With this in mind, the plot will just be of that scalar function (you could pretend there are "up" and down arrows from the $xy$ plane to the plot, if you prefer), and we get:

[`vectorplot cross((sin(x),sin(y)),(sin(1-x),sin(y))) for x from 0 to pi and y from 0 to pi`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=vectorplot%20cross((sin(x),sin(y)),(sin(1-x),sin(y)))%20for%20x%20from%200%20to%20pi%20and%20y%20from%200%20to%20pi)

[image: F4 3d plot]
[image: F4 contour plot]

Comment: Thanks, yes I actually did want $\sin(\pi-x)$ but didn't realize until now. That would make $\vec F_3$ vertical right

Comment: @Ultradark While it would be good practice for you to get Wolfram|Alpha to show you the answer, it's also good to review your basic trig. How does $\sin(\pi-x)$ relate to $\sin(x)$? What does that do to the $x$ components of $\vec F_1+\vec F_2$?